# How to Save a menu items (text) into dynamic Session states

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session, menubar

Okay , below is the code for populating menu items dynamically from a database table.
now what i want to do is to save the **"PageHeader"** from the database into **sessions states** so that i can use those session values to check the authorization of a user on Page-load of different content pages.
now since every user have different no. of authorized pages so the no. of sessions will vary from user to user. the values of those sessions will be matched with a **PageHeader** variable on the Page-Load of content pages.

1. can someone help me how to go about it.
2. also i want to change the style of the menu-bar which is otherwise
   default and very  simple.

---

```
private void GetMenu()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = bll.master_Menu_Bar(en);
    DataRow[] drow = dt.Select();
    foreach (DataRow dr in drow)
    {
        MenuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["PageHeader"].ToString(), dr["PageId"].ToString(), "", dr["PageUrl"].ToString()));
    }
```

---

business logic layer method used in above code is:

```
public DataTable master_Menu_Bar(EntityLayer.Entity en)
    {
        return dll.ReturnSingleTable("Select PageHeader,PageUrl from authorized_view where Emp_Mobile="+ en.cal_EmpMobile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my simple code which does the thing ..

```
 private void GetMenu()
{
//fetches data from business logic layer
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1 = bll.Master_Menu_Bar(en);
//session so that the masterpage doesnt interact with database on everypostback
    Session["dataTable"] = dt1;
    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
    dt=(DataTable)Session["dataTable"];
//session for page id's of the menuitems which will be checked for authorization at page loads of every page.
    int i = 0;
    while (i < dt.Rows.Count)
    {
        int[] PageId = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
        PageId[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][2]);
        Session["PageId" + i] = PageId[i];
        i++;

    }
//A session to keep count of the no. of menu items , this session is also used at page loads of pages as condition of if statement
    Session["count"] = dt.Rows.Count;
    DataRow[] drow = dt.Select();
    foreach (DataRow dr in drow)
    {
        MenuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["PageHeader"].ToString(), dr["PageId"].ToString(), "", dr["PageUrl"].ToString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a `list of string` and `put your menu items in there`, then put that string list in session

later retrieve from the session only.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in drow)
    {
      //add items to list here
    }
 //make menu from that list
 //put that in session or view state
```

### Updated

How to make it store Page Id, Page Url, and Page headers

First we declare a class

```
 public Class MenuHelper
{
   public String PageId {get; set;}
   public String PageHeader {get; set;}
   public String PageUrl {get; set;}
}
```

The how we do it

List menulist = new List();

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = bll.master_Menu_Bar(en);
DataRow[] drow = dt.Select();
foreach (DataRow dr in drow)
{
    MenuHelper helperItem = new MenuHelper();
    helperItem.PageId = dr["PageId"].ToString();
    helperItem.PageHeader = dr["PageHeader"].ToString();
    helperItem.PageUrl = dr["PageUrl"].ToString();
    //can add menu here or not
    MenuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["PageHeader"].ToString(), dr["PageId"].ToString(), "", dr["PageUrl"].ToString()));
    //Add items to list
    menulist.Add(helperItem);
}

//Add list to session or view state
Session["MenuItems"] = menulist;

//When retrieving list do like this

List<MenuHelper> menulist = (List<MenuHelper>)Session["MenuItems"];
```

Comment: Can you explain how to add pageHeaders as text page ids as value and pageurl as nav urls to that list ?
and how to make menu from the list....
i mean you could only add a single column value the dataset in that list how would it be converted to menu after ?